# Sending mail through mailgun api using only client side ajax request

Tags: ajax, email, mailgun, axios

I am working on localhost (inside a static React web app) and on form submit, I want to send an email through my contact form. So I am posting to the mailgun api like so:

```
   axios({
      url: 'https://api:key-someapikey@api.mailgun.net/v3/somesandboxdomain1c.mailgun.org/messages',
      method: 'post',
      username: 'api',
      password: 'key-somekey',
      data: {
        from: "Excited User <mailgun@some.example.org>",
        to: "myemail@gmail.com",
        subject: "Hello from react app",
        text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Authorization': `Basic ${window.btoa('api:key-someapikey')}`
      }
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

But I keep getting this error or one of it's variations:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mailgun.net/v3/somesandbox.mailgun.org. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I am using a static web app and have no server through which to send data. I have already tried adding and removing various headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` etc. Nothing seems to work

Comment: did you figure this out? i thought you could only send from a server

Comment: @timh no you have to use a server

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I'm answering it too late, but you can try this:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${mailgun.baseUrl}/${mailgun.domain}/messages`,
    auth: {
        username: 'api',
        password: mailgun.apiKey
    },
    params: {
        from: 'Awesome Development Team <noreply@yourdomain.com>',
        to: 'testing@example.com',
        subject: 'Hello',
        text: 'Welcome to the team!'
    }
}).then(
    response => {
        console.log(response)
    },
    reject => {
        console.log(reject)
    }
)
```

Mailgun documentation states that it accepts Request Parameters instead of Request Body, so in Axios you use should use *params* instead of *data*.

As for the Basic Auth required by Mailgun, Axios does provide a better way to do so, that is supplying a auth object (Refer to the code above)

You can refer to these links for more details

- https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending
- https://github.com/axios/axios (Scroll to Request Config)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`params` works for `{from, to, subject, template}` but if you want to use `h:X-My-Variable` like `h:Reply-To` or `v:Recipient-Var`, you'll have to use `data` instead of `params`.

```
axios({
 url: `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/${domain}/messages`,
 method: 'POST',
 auth: {
   username: 'api',
   password: functions.config().mailgun.key, //using firebase functions here
 },
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 },
 data: new URLSearchParams({
   from: `"Foo bot" <noreply@foobot.com>`,
   to: 'foo@bar.com'
   subject: "Hello",
   template: 'my_template',
   'v:customVar': foobar,
 })
})
```